# TensorRT Inference is giving partial output

Tags: c++, nvidia, tensorrt, onnxruntime

**Description**
(Already posted in Nvidia forum, but posting here for quicker responses. Ref:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/2795)
I am using a ONNX model which take input (n,2) as input and returns the negation of the input as output.
Ex: Input = [ [ -1.1, -2.2], [ 3.3, 4.4]]
Output = [ [ 1.1, 2.2], [ -3.3, -4.4]]

But in my case output (reading in flat manner) is coming as 1.1 2.2 0 0.
Part of output is missing. I didn't see anything wrong in my buffer allocation.

**Environment**

```
TensorRT Version: 8.5.3.x
NVIDIA GPU: A100
NVIDIA Driver Version:
CUDA Version: 10.2.x
CUDNN Version: 8.4.x_Cuda_10.2.x
Operating System: Cent OS
```

**Relevant Files**

run.cpp
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auhnl7nI-7bxgsAaNh0qK_0WMVIIMA?e=tFzvxF

negative_model_2d.onnx file
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auhnl7nI-7bxgsAZEccWbe9B0syvdA?e=zquGLO
Steps To Reproduce

**Cmake**

```
add_executable(trt_sample tensorrt/run.cpp)
target_include_directories(trt_sample PUBLIC ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${TensorRT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(trt_sample PUBLIC ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${TensorRT_LIBRARIES})
# below line is not working. also, in custom_build made make -j8 from make install
install(TARGETS trt_sample
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

run the C++ file with relevant dependencies.

```
./trt_sample negative_model_2d.onnx
```

**log**

```
Parsing the negative_model_2d.onnx
setting op1
building engine
building context
Parsing done for negative_model_2d.onnx
 total bindings 2
83 86 77 15
setting 2d input
-83 -86 0 0
```

**code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <NvInfer.h>
#include <NvOnnxParser.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

// utilities ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class to log errors, warnings, and other information during the build and inference phases
class Logger : public nvinfer1::ILogger
{
public:
    void log(Severity severity, const char* msg) noexcept override {
        // remove this 'if' if you need more logged info
        if ((severity == Severity::kERROR) || (severity == Severity::kINTERNAL_ERROR)) {
            std::cout << msg << "\n";
        }
    }
} gLogger;

// destroy TensorRT objects if something goes wrong
struct TRTDestroy
{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T* obj) const
    {
        if (obj)
        {
            obj->destroy();
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
using TRTUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T, TRTDestroy>;

// initialize TensorRT engine and parse ONNX model --------------------------------------------------------------------
void parseOnnxModel(const std::string& model_path, TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::ICudaEngine>& engine,
                    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::IExecutionContext>& context)
{
    const auto explicitBatch = 1U << static_cast<uint32_t>(nvinfer1::NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag::kEXPLICIT_BATCH);
    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::IBuilder> builder{nvinfer1::createInferBuilder(gLogger)};
    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::INetworkDefinition> network{builder->createNetworkV2(explicitBatch)};
    TRTUniquePtr<nvonnxparser::IParser> parser{nvonnxparser::createParser(*network, gLogger)};
    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::IBuilderConfig> config{builder->createBuilderConfig()};
    // parse ONNX
    if (!parser->parseFromFile(model_path.c_str(), static_cast<int>(nvinfer1::ILogger::Severity::kINFO)))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: could not parse the model.\n";
        return;
    }
    // allow TensorRT to use up to 1GB of GPU memory for tactic selection.
    config->setMaxWorkspaceSize(24 * (1ULL << 30));
    // use FP16 mode if possible
    if (builder->platformHasFastFp16())
    {
        config->setFlag(nvinfer1::BuilderFlag::kFP16);
    }
    // we have only one image in batch
    builder->setMaxBatchSize(2);
    // add optimization profile
    std::cout << "setting op1" << std::endl;
    nvinfer1::IOptimizationProfile* profile = builder->createOptimizationProfile();
    profile->setDimensions("input_1", nvinfer1::OptProfileSelector::kMIN,  nvinfer1::Dims2(2,2));
    profile->setDimensions("input_1", nvinfer1::OptProfileSelector::kOPT, nvinfer1::Dims2(2,2));
    profile->setDimensions("input_1", nvinfer1::OptProfileSelector::kMAX, nvinfer1::Dims2(2,2));
    config->addOptimizationProfile(profile);

    std::cout << "building engine" << std::endl;
    // generate TensorRT engine optimized for the target platform
    engine.reset(builder->buildEngineWithConfig(*network, *config));
    std::cout << "building context" << std::endl;
    context.reset(engine->createExecutionContext());
}

// main pipeline ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " model.onnx\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::string model_path(argv[1]);
    // initialize TensorRT engine and parse ONNX model
    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::ICudaEngine> engine{nullptr};
    TRTUniquePtr<nvinfer1::IExecutionContext> context{nullptr};
    std::cout << "Parsing the " << model_path << std::endl;
    parseOnnxModel(model_path, engine, context);
    std::cout << "Parsing done for " << model_path << std::endl;
    nvinfer1::Dims2 inputDims_b1{2,2};
    context->setBindingDimensions(0, inputDims_b1);
    std::cout << " total bindings " << engine->getNbBindings() << std::endl;
    std::vector<void*> buffers(engine->getNbBindings()); // buffers for input and output data
    float td_inputTensor[2][2];
    float td_outputTensor[2][2];
    size_t pitch;
    size_t pitch2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            td_inputTensor[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            std::cout << td_inputTensor[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "setting 2d input" << std::endl;
    cudaMallocPitch(&buffers[0], &pitch, 2 * sizeof(float), 2);
    cudaMallocPitch(&buffers[1], &pitch2, 2 * sizeof(float), 2);
    cudaMemcpy2D(buffers[0], pitch, td_inputTensor, 2*sizeof(float), 2*sizeof(float), 2, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    context->enqueue(2, buffers.data(), 0, nullptr);
    cudaMemcpy2D(td_outputTensor, 2 * sizeof(float), buffers[1], pitch2, 2 * sizeof(float), 2, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            std::cout << td_outputTensor[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "release buffers " << std::endl;
    for (void* buf : buffers)
    {
        cudaFree(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```